# Jmeter Mocking the Respose (Stubs) from JMS Endpoint

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am planning to use Jmeter for performance and load testing .

we have JMS/Camel as endpoints for request and response.

I dont have actual server to respond to the request. i need to mock the response by creating stubs.

is it possible in Jmeter or suggest me any other tools if any?

Comment: Looks like it is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130518