# How to send http request without waiting for response from server

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

We are planning to do load testing of our server and we need to generate heavy load from Jmeter tool. But as per i know, jmeter waits for the response to create another request thread. Is there a way to create http request without waiting for response from the server using jmeter? if not, what are the available work around to generate heavy load keeping number of threads fixed?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129938/can-jmeter-mock-http-request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Define a very small timeout in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better in [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) so the setting would be applied to all HTTP Request samplers) like 1 millisecond so JMeter will close the connection right after sending the request

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults Timeout]
2. (Optional) To avoid JMeter marking requests as failed add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and tick `Ignore Status` box

   [image: JMeter Assertion Ignore Status]

Answer (score 1):

You can set in [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) in the Advanced tab Timeout of Connect and Response with 1 ms

> Connect Timeout Connection Timeout. Number of milliseconds to wait for a connection to open.
>
> Response Timeout Response Timeout. Number of milliseconds to wait for a response. Note that this applies to each wait for a response.

If you need to return always success you can add with [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use [prev](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) variable:

```
prev.setSuccessful(true)
```