# JMeter mock json response

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

Is there a way to make a request on JMeter and receive a mocked JSON response that I create, for example:

```
[
 {
   "Car": "BMW",
   "Model": "520D",
   "Color": "Black"
 },
 {
   "Car": "Audi",
   "Model": "A3",
   "Color": "Red"
 },
 {
   "Car": "Ford",
   "Model": "Focus",
   "Color": "Blue"
 }
]
```

I need a mocked up response that I can practice on using JMeter samplers etc.

Comment: I posted this from my phone. I am not sure why the json came up like that. Hmm

Comment: take a look at http://www.mock-server.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mock the entire request/response use [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/), just set Response Data field with your JSON and it'll return it:

[image]

If you want to mock only the response, meaning send to a real server the request, see [mock http request answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129938/can-jmeter-mock-http-request) Which suggests using a third party,  as WireMock or mock-server.com as @Kiril S. suggested in comments

Another option is to manipulate response using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129938/can-jmeter-mock-http-request)

Use [SampleResult.setResponseData](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseData-java.lang.String-) to set JSON, for example:

```
prev.setResponseData("[ {   \"Car\": \"BMW\" }]","UTF-8");
```