# Localhost connection refused when integrating WireMock and JMeter

Tags: jmeter, wiremock

I'm trying to integrate Wiremock into a Jmeter test plan so that every time I execute the test plan it will start up an instance of WireMock in the beginning and then run tests I have outlined. I followed this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130518/12912945) but the problem I am having is that I always get the error:

```
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

From what I can see, the Wiremock server never starts even though I have the following code in a JSR223 Sampler at the beginning of the test plan:

```
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;

public class WireMockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer();
        configureFor("127.0.0.1", 8080);
        wireMockServer.start();
        StubMapping foo = stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody("Hello World")));
        wireMockServer.addStubMapping(foo);
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to correctly integrate the two, I have tried adding to the classpath but I feel like I have not done this correctly or I'm missing something

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining the [`main` function](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method) but I failed to see where you're executing it. In other words your Wiremock initialization code isn't getting executed at all.

You need to explicitly call this `main` function in order to get your code executed, to get this done add the next line to the end of your script:

```
WireMockTest.main()
```

Once done the JSR223 Sampler will invoke the code inside the `main` function and the Wiremock server will be started.

Another option is to remove these `class` and function declarations and just use

```
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;

WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer();
configureFor("127.0.0.1", 8080);
wireMockServer.start();
StubMapping foo = stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
      .willReturn(aResponse()
              .withStatus(200)
              .withBody("Hello World")));
wireMockServer.addStubMapping(foo);
```

as the script you define in the JSR223 Test elements don't require an [entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) article for more information about Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.