# Mocking API response in Jmeter with WireMock

Tags: jmeter, wiremock

Is it possible to mock the json response of an API in Jmeter using WireMock.
If yes, can you please share the step by step process for that.

Comment: you don't want to send a real request, just mock it? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129938/can-jmeter-mock-http-request/49130518#49130518

Answer (score 1):

Wiremock is a separate standalone Java application, you can [run it as the different process](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/) like:

```
java -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-x.xx.x.jar --port 8080
```

and once you add stub mappings using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers or JSON configuration files the mock responses will be returned according to the stub mappings.

Wiremock can be launched using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) like:

[image]