# How to mock service calls Jmeter when using Jms publisher?

Tags: java, api, jmeter, wiremock

I have a Jmeter script that has a JMS publisher to send a payload to an activeMQ queue. When the message is sent to this queue, it goes through the flow and calls different endpoints. I want to be able to mock one of these API endpoints so that when it's called, it will just give generic response with 1 second delay instead of errors or repeating the same call.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: See similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129938/can-jmeter-mock-http-request

Comment: Does using wireMock apply to JMS publisher as well?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what kind of "API" endpoints are being "called" and what protocols are in scope hence we cannot come up with a comprehensive solution.

- Well-behaved and well-developed systems should allow simple configuration switch which would return a dummy response from an "API endpoint" whatever it means. If it's not the case - I doubt that it makes sense to conduct performance testing because given bad initial architecture I assume that it won't handle even several concurrent threads.
- If you need to just pretend that some endpoint returns something to JMeter - go for [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/)
- A very simple HTTP mock response can be supplied using JMeter's built-in [HTTP Mirror Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server)
- More comprehensive solution would be using a dedicated mocking tool like [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/)
- If you need to supply a fully functional mock of a JMS endpoint (a real queue or topic) - check out [Mocking JMS infrastructure with MockRunner to favour testing](https://dzone.com/articles/mocking-jms-infrastructure) article